# Modify XML document inside the browser

Tags: javascript, xml

Is it possible to modify/write data to an XML file without any server-side proxy(e.g. a php or asp script)? Can this be done via javascript? XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load and modify xml in browser, but writing the file back is a different thing.

I don't know of any feasible way of writing data back to a server without some kind of server side mechanism to write the data to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Using the XMLHTTPRequest object you can modify an XML document using XSLT.  Here's a [sample](http://aspalliance.com/1067_Creating_a_Menu_Using_XSLT_XML_and_JavaScript) article for getting started.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible. You can do it with pure javascript or using a library like [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Browsed through this article on site point http://www.sitepoint.com/print/xml-javascript-mozilla/

The author of the article mentioned it is NOT possible to write to an XML file using client-side javascript. He wrote this near the bottom of his article. But you claim this is possible.I'm confused.

Comment: The server remains responsible for writing to disk. The server might provide an API to do so, which can be called from javascript, but without a serverside mechanism in place, it's not possible. Period.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question

Comment: This is a million years old in web years but I think nowadays you could do this with AJAX or JSON saving back to the XML file.  Which is exactly what I am looking for.